# What will happen when the velocity of the car is greater than the rated speed at a banked turn?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, centripetal-force

There can be three scenarios:

1. $N\sin\theta=\frac{mv^2}{r}$: the car will be able to take a turn nicely.
2. $N\sin\theta\ge\frac{mv^2}{r}$: the car will skid inwards following a curved line until $r$ has decreased enough so that $N\sin\theta=\frac{mv^2}{r}$ becomes true again. Then, the car will continue turning with its new and smaller radius of curvature. The skidding inwards of the car can be viewed as $mg\sin\theta$ acting on the car. $N$ & $mg\cos\theta$ cancel each other out and $mg\sin\theta$ is the only force that remains.[image: free].
3. $N\sin\theta\le\frac{mv^2}{r}$: the car will skid outwards following a curved line until $r$ has increased enough so that $N\sin\theta=\frac{mv^2}{r}$ becomes true again. Then, the car will continue turning with its new and greater radius of curvature, but my question is, what force acts on the car while it is skidding outwards?

Comment: What do you mean by "what force acts"?  Assuming a frictionless surface, you've already described the two forces that can act on the car (gravity & the normal force);  there aren't any others.  Can you elaborate on what you want to know about these forces?

Comment: Use a slightly different coordinate basis to make your life simple.  That is, define the gravitational and normal forces in terms of horizontal and vertical.  You will see that the vertical must balance (i.e., the car isn't hopping or falling), then you need only balance the horizontal to find the frictionless limit speed.  Add in friction and the speed increases before sliding up the ramp occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centrifugal force, $F_r$ acts on the car:

$$F_r=\frac{mv^2}{r}-mg\sin\theta$$

If $F_r$ is positive, the car goes outwards and if it is negative, the car goes inwards.

Apparently, this phenomenon is difficult to understand using inertial frames of reference. So, centrifugal force has been used to explain this.

Furthermore, your explanation of the situation when the car skids inwards is wrong. The correct explanation, given by @JohnRennie at the h bar is as follows:

> Suppose we start with a speed less than the equilibrium speed. Then Fr
> is negative so the car starts accelerating inwards. Yes? But remember
> that force has been accelerating the car inwards all the time the car
> took to reach the point where the net force is zero, so at this
> instant the car has a radial velocity inwards. That means the car goes
> past the equilibrium point and carries on moving to smaller r. As it
> moves towards smaller r the net force becomes positive i.e. it starts
> pushing the car outwards again. So the inward motion of the cars slows
> then stops, and the car starts moving outwards again. So the car will
> not spiral in to the point where the net force is zero then remain at
> that distance. Instead it will oscillate inwards and outwards. The
> average distance will be the distance at which the net force is zero,
> but the car will continually oscillate around this average distance.

Also, you might have another question: "what relation does the normal force have with the radius of rotation/velocity of the car?"

@JohnRennie comes with the save again:

> The two forces are the gravitational force acting vertically downwards
> and the centrifugal (fictional) force acting horizontally outwards.
> Both of these contribute to the normal force. i.e. the gravitational
> force contributes a term $mg\cos\theta$ and the centrifugal force
> contributes $F_r\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 4):

The car skids outwards because the $N\sin\theta$ force is not enough to provide the centripetal force $\frac{mv^2}{r}$.

If you are wondering how the car gains height, it's the momentum of the car that causes it.

Looking from above and approximating the motion of the car as a straight line tangential to the circle, the car would naturally come to higher parts of the banked track.

However it will lose some kinetic energy whilst doing that - just as a ball rolled up a hill will move upwards, even though there is no component of force acting up the slope of the hill.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you are missing friction force, which plays an important role in the dynamics of this problem (but it will not affect your final question).

To answer this question, I look at it this way: Suppose you have an end of a string in your hand and the other end of it attached to a mass m, you start turning the mass with the speed of $v$ at a radius of $r$. After a few seconds, you feel your hand is tired, so you let the rope slide in your hand until the mass reaches a new radius $R, R>r$, then you hold the rope again and the mass keeps turning. What makes the mass slide out to a bigger radius is the LACK OF sufficient centrifugal force to keep it in that radius. Another example is when a train derails at a turn.